# Fonts and colors extension for Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions

**[Visual Studio Color Theme Editor](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/20cd93a2-c435-4d00-a797-499f16402378)** is an excellent extension for Visual Studio 2010 that can be used to try and apply different themes on the IDE. The theme only changes the chrome or the windowing area of the IDE.

To change the display of code one still has to play around with the settings in the **Fonts and Colors** dialog or import settings from a `.vssettings` file. (A variety of styles are available at **[StudioStyles](http://studiostyl.es/)**).

All editors now allow the programmer to try or switch between different styles on the code with a click (like the gorgeous **[Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/)**). Is there a Visual Studio extension or external tool that makes it easy to apply and play around with different styles? If not, is there some trick to try or switch between different styles with ease? I find that going through the Import Settings dialog is quite onerous.

Comment: I was looking for one myself but didn't find any. That Theme Editor thing is useless.

Comment: Those two are the only options to customize VS2010.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Visual Studio **2012** Color Theme Editor](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/366ad100-0003-4c9a-81a8-337d4e7ace05) extension now allows (from v2.3) to change Font colors using styles (include your own styles). Exactly what do you need.

> Version history
>   2.3  Added support for merging Fonts & Colors customizations with a theme

Answer (score 0):

Update to Visual Studio 2012 and you be able to use either Light or Dark theme. What's is really cool.

Other good suggestion is to check http://studiostyl.es/ - This website provide many variations of color and fonts to use with your Visual Studio (but by now that compatibility is just with vs2005, vs2008 and vs2010)